# Plotly Vertical Box Plot on Numerical Logarithmic X-Axis

Tags: python, plot, plotly, boxplot

I wanted to use Plotly (tried and failed with seaborn as well) to plot a results of an experiment that measures model performance for different hyperparameter values. There are 20 different hyper parameter values, so I want to plot 20 vertical box plots on logarithmic horizontal axis.

The desired output is something like this, but with the real C values (varies between 10^-10 and 10^10 on the horizontal axis instead of the normalised interval from -20 to 15.:
[image]

However, Plotly aggregates many of the experiments with small C values, instead of putting a new box plot for each. I could change the numerical values of C as categorical inputs and obtain 20 box plots clearly, but I would loose their position on the x axis. I want to present their numerical comparison as well.

Do you know any way in Python to manage this?

**Minimum working example:**

Small sampled set of the data in *df.csv*:

```
,C,Aggregated CV Scores - f1_weighted
74,0.0018650170653294505,0.9072978665065649
115,0.036702477028033614,0.9267488997073684
156,2581.9216397919195,0.8557789569356158
51,1.5336577202335394e-05,0.3993185490172851
18,1.1771126646389649e-09,0.304696897236352
191,20278296.734494094,0.8807177343051323
53,1.5336577202335394e-05,0.422701718200912
99,0.011630035353741785,0.9194633715958328
135,5.8325343372386245,0.8818640374812505
96,0.011630035353741785,0.9279111843536404
27,3.2741895449930884e-08,0.304696897236352
108,0.028725560529468182,0.9094861818093469
141,812.0180339074607,0.8698559540062134
158,2581.9216397919195,0.8806930657698903
1,4.630723947421749e-10,0.30386296177866423
5,4.630723947421749e-10,0.304696897236352
16,1.1771126646389649e-09,0.304696897236352
100,0.028725560529468182,0.9100666457392884
128,3.2467791652601545,0.8855105984927174
112,0.036702477028033614,0.9126486993427462
61,0.0001779899985286896,0.8484080382190846
34,3.976515442097236e-07,0.3064621197316135
168,1537831.4714003839,0.8806469846313258
157,2581.9216397919195,0.8739001212699548
22,3.2741895449930884e-08,0.30386296177866423
116,0.036702477028033614,0.9231063513259355
77,0.0018650170653294505,0.9253848883312678
48,5.182763460211468e-06,0.304696897236352
164,1537831.4714003839,0.8827843186170564
59,1.5336577202335394e-05,0.4149282748729963
71,0.0018650170653294505,0.9182826681498876
72,0.0018650170653294505,0.9196305779619918
176,3136815.7093541413,0.862102892449218
42,5.182763460211468e-06,0.30386296177866423
19,1.1771126646389649e-09,0.304696897236352
113,0.036702477028033614,0.9115709310968896
196,20278296.734494094,0.8619886204842211
186,9542231.981025452,0.8653933127325344
125,3.2467791652601545,0.8869306096746981
89,0.0029963713517767365,0.9353446653142417
30,3.976515442097236e-07,0.30386296177866423
79,0.0018650170653294505,0.9282558584572858
41,5.182763460211468e-06,0.30386296177866423
170,3136815.7093541413,0.8418187034364125
165,1537831.4714003839,0.8777678904725902
118,0.036702477028033614,0.9046283335326759
8,4.630723947421749e-10,0.304696897236352
35,3.976515442097236e-07,0.304696897236352
70,0.0018650170653294505,0.9025434213315724
171,3136815.7093541413,0.8759182769056508
```

Unique set of *C* values:

```
[4.630723947421749e-10,
 1.1771126646389649e-09,
 3.2741895449930884e-08,
 3.976515442097236e-07,
 5.182763460211468e-06,
 1.5336577202335394e-05,
 0.0001779899985286896,
 0.0018650170653294505,
 0.0029963713517767365,
 0.011630035353741785,
 0.028725560529468182,
 0.036702477028033614,
 3.2467791652601545,
 5.8325343372386245,
 812.0180339074607,
 2581.9216397919195,
 1537831.4714003839,
 3136815.7093541413,
 9542231.981025452,
 20278296.734494094]
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./df.csv', index_col=0, header=0)
x_label = 'C'
y_label = 'Aggregated CV Scores - f1_weighted'
```

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Box(x=df[x_label], y=df[y_label]))
fig.update_xaxes(type="log")
fig.show()
```

[image: output for 1st try]

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.box(df, x=x_label, y=y_label, log_x=True, points="all")
fig.show()
```

[image: output for 2nd try]

```
import itertools
import operator
xys = df.groupby(x_label).groups.items()
it1, it2 = itertools.tee(xys)
xs = list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), it1))
ys = list(map(lambda x: df.loc[x][y_label].tolist(), map(operator.itemgetter(1), it2)))
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.update_xaxes(type="log")
fig.add_trace(go.Box(x=xs, y=ys))
fig.show()
```

[image: output from 3rd try]

Best,